# Why LSP keep giving "Client 1 quit with exit code 1 and signal 0" error (lua_ls)?

Tags: lua, configuration, windows-10, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I'm trying to configuring my lua *LSP*, but it's keep giving me `"Client 1 quit with exit code 1 and signal 0"` warning and it (the LSP) won't run. I don't know why it happen. It keeps printing that warning message every time I open a lua file.

---

### Neovim (Windows 10)

```
NVIM v0.9.2
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.1694082368
Compilation: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe /MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1  -W3 -wd4311 -wd4146 -DUNIT_TESTING -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0602 -DMSWIN -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include/luajit-2.1 -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/build/src/nvim/auto -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/build/include -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/build/cmake.config -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/src -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include -ID:/a/neovim/neovim/.deps/usr/include

   system vimrc file: "$VIM\sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "C:/Program Files (x86)/nvim/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

---

### Code

```
vim.lsp.set_log_level "debug"

local ready, lspconfig = pcall(require, "lspconfig")
if not ready then
  print "ERROR: C:/User/Alpha/AppData/Local/nvim/plugin/lspconfig rc.lua: Failed to load nvim-lspconfig"
  return
end

local protocol = require "vim.lsp.protocol"

local augroup_format = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("Format", { clear = true })
local enable_format_on_save = function(_, bufnr)
  vim.api.nvim_clear_autocmds { group = augroup_format, buffer = bufnr }

  vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePre", {
    group = augroup_format,
    buffer = bufnr,
    callback = function()
      vim.lsp.buf.format { bufnr = bufnr }
    end
  })
end

local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  local function buf_set_keymap(...)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, ...)
  end

  local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }

  buf_set_keymap("n", "gd", "<Cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "gi", "<Cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "K", "<Cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>", opts)
end

-- local capabilities = require "cmp_lspconfig .default_capabilities()

lspconfig.clangd.setup {
  on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    client.server_capabilities.signatureHelpProvider = false
    on_attach(client, bufnr)
  end,

  -- capabilities = capabilities
}

lspconfig.lua_ls.setup {
  on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    on_attach(client, bufnr)
    enable_format_on_save(client, bufnr)
  end,

  -- capabilities = capabilities

  settings = {
    Lua = {
      diagnostics = {
        globals = { "vim" },
      },

      workspace = {
        library = vim.api.nvim_get_runtime_file("", true),
        checkThirdParty = false
      }
    }
  }
}

vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/publishDiagnostics"] = vim.lsp.with(
  vim.lsp.diagnostic.on_publish_diagnostics, {
    underline = true,
    update_in_insert = false,
    virtual_text = { spacing = 4, prefix = "\u{ea71}" },
    severity_sort = true
  }
)

local signs = { Error = " ", Warn = " ", Hint = " ", Info = " " }
for type, icon in pairs(signs) do
  local hl = "DiagnosticSign" .. type
  vim.fn.sign_define(hl, { text = icon, texthl = hl, numhl = "" })
end

vim.diagnostic.config {
  virtual_text = {
    prefix = "●"
  },

  update_in_insert = true,

  float = {
    source = "always"
  }
}
```

---

### Result

```
Client 1 quit with exit code 1 and signal 0
```

My [:LspInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8FAf.png) result.

---

### Expectation

That warning message dissapear and the LSP work.

Comment: what's in the lsp log? You can see path to it in a LspInfo dialog. What happens when you try to run lus ls manually from cmd.exe?

Comment: @MonsieurMerso I don't really know how to insert an image of the LspInfo, but here's the image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8FAf.png. Is "lus ls" supposed to be "lua_ls"/"lua-language-server"? if it's right, it just prints:
Content-Length: 120
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/status/report","params":{"text":"≡ƒÿ║Lua","tooltip":"Cached files: 0/0\nMemory usage: 2M"}}"

Comment: I meant contents of the lsp log, PATH to the log you can see in the LspInfo dialog

Comment: @MonsieurMerso Ahh, my bad. Here is the link: https://pastebin.com/9LEVG4VJ. I hope it's the log that you mean.

Comment: there _Access denied_ errors in log. Try fixing permission on our lua-lsp installation, it looks like lua-lsp server fails to access certain files.

Comment: @MonsieurMerso after reinstalling it, it's working now. Thank you for helping me!